# Is there a way I can combine these formulas to just one cell?

Tags: python, excel-formula

I am checking spreadsheets for a certain pattern in a column. I have a formula to check for the pattern, which will be Flagged or be Fine, and then another to check if there has been a Flag. 
I am using 2 formulas as the spreadsheets will be extracted and edited using Python and it seemed like the easiest way for now. I am also looking into ways I can use Python to do this more efficiently.

I am trying to match patterns of five 0's in either column A,B or C. It doesn't really matter which column it checks.

```
A   B   C   D     E
379 400 51  fine  Flagged
404 460 18  fine    
379 365 65  fine    
0   0   0   fine    
0   0   0   Flag    
0   0   0   fine    
0   0   0   fine    
0   0   0   fine    
399 480 94  fine    
390 420 55  fine    
399 435 121 fine
```

In column D I have this formula to find the pattern:

```
=IF((AND(A5=0, A6=0, A7=0, A8=0, A9=0 )), "Flag", "Fine")
```

And then this formula to check if any in D are flagged:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH("Flag",W:W,0), "Flagged"), "Fine")
```

This is so Python can just check 1 cell (my python skills are still developing)

If there was one formula I could that could be pasted into just one cell to give the Flag or Fine result for the spreadsheet, that would be perfect.
Thanks

EDIT/ANSWER 4.9.19
In the end there was no formula I could find to use in a single cell. The way around was to use python to iterate through the cells, pasting the formula as needed:

```
    for i in range(3,max_row+1):
          cell_obj=sheet.cell(row=i,column=24)
          # print cell value     
          print(cell_obj.value)
          #5-in a row fault
          formula = "=IF((AND(O%d=0, O%d=0, O%d=0, O%d=0, O%d=0)), A1, A2)" % (i-2, i-1, i, i+1, i+2)
          #3-in a row fault
          formula = "=IF((AND(O%d=0, O%d=0, O%d=0)), A1, A2)" % (i-1, i, i+1)
          cell_obj.value = formula
          print(cell_obj.value)
    sheet["Y2"] = "=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A1,X:X,0), A3), A4)"
```

Comment: Just to confirm, if any of A, B, and C column has five `0` consecutively, you want to return `Flag` in column D? Where did you put the IF formula provided in the post? What's the formula you put in `Cell D1`? Are you basically finding if there is five consecutive `0` across the three columns range you want to return `Flagged`?

Comment: You'd need an array formula to get the result in one cell. Are you entering the formula in Excel or in Python? Can an array formula be entered in Python?

Comment: Terry W - thanks Terry. 5 in a row on a column seems to do the job. 5x3 is technically ideal, but practically doesn't seem to matter at this stage

Comment: teylyn - thanks teylyn. Right now I'm testing manually and then working through to python. I have looked at an array formula but am not sure how I could use it in this case. If you have any ideas that would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: @GlennDavies **"Python can just check 1 cell"***: [Edit] your question and sho your attemp.

Answer (score 0):

Read your spreadsheet in pandas. If you are parsing a lot of rows, best to use `read_csv` than `read_excel` since the csv file would smaller than an xlxs.

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_filename.csv', header = 0)
```

Then use `np.where()` method to place the tag you want in column D.

```
df['D'] = np.where((df['A'] == 0) & (df['B'] == 0) & (df['C'] == 0), ['Flag'], ['Fine'])
```

To get the column `F` you'll have to reference your column `D` right? To do that, use `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['D'] == 'Flag', 'F'] = 'Flagged'
```

I'm not sure which value to tag `'Flagged'` with on `F` is it if your column `D` value equals `'Fine'`? In your example above, you tag column `F` as `'Flagged'` with a column `D` value of `'Fine'`. In that case, just change the value in the condition above to what you need.